# Access ActionExecutingContext inside of method in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I have a logging action filter which performs logging if required on the OnActionExecuting event of the methods decorated with a custom attribute. This filter is declared globally.

```
public class LoggerFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        PerformLoggingIfNecessary(filterContext);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    private static void PerformLoggingIfNecessary(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var allAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        CustomAttribute myAttribute = (CustomAttribute)allAttributes .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(CustomAttribute));
        if (myAttribute != null)
        {
            LogClass myLog = BuildLogClass(filterContext);                
            Logger.Log(myLog);
        }
    }
}
```

When an action is decorated with the "CustomAttribute" attribute, then a log is created with properties assigned to the CustomAttribute and with properties obtained from the ActionExecutingContext such as the ControllerName, the ActionName or the ActionParameters. If such action is not decorated then logging is not performed (though the OnActionExecuting of the LoggerFilter is triggered).

However, this logging ALWAYS takes place, independently of the model received on the action. What I want to do is to validate the model received and if it succeeds, perform logging. i.e.

```
[CustomAttribute (ParameterOne, ParameterTwo)]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel someModel)
    {
        if(someModel.Verify()){ //I cannot use ModelState.IsValid
            //Call the OnActionExecuting to perform logging
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        //DO NOT LOG
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Could you not get the value of the input parameter inside your filter and validate it? You might run the `Validate` method twice but if it doesn´t involve database access it might still be cheap

Comment: I cannot because it does involve DB access

Comment: Hum, then maybe you could do the logging `OnActionExecuted`, depending on the result of the action? You could also create a specirfic model binder that calls Validate and adds error to the ModelState, this way you could check the ModelState.IsValid in both the filter and the controller